# Targeting a div associated with a checked radio button using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

HTML

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="target"></div>
   <input type="radio">
</div>

<div class="container">
   <div class="target"></div>
   <input type="radio">
</div>

<div class="container">
   <div class="target"></div>
   <input type="radio">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.target {
   background-color: red;
}

.active {
   background-color: blue;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.target').each(function(){
      if ($('.container:has(input:radio:checked)')) {
      $(this).addClass('active');
   }
   });
});
```

The above adds the `class` `active` to all `.target` **div's**.What I need it to do is add an `active` `class` to the `.target` `div` associated with the currently `checked radio` **only**.

I tried using `$(this).parent('div').addClass('active');` and various other things but I'm not winning :-S

Not sure if I should be using .each either?

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try modifying your jQuery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("input[type='radio']:checked").each(function(){
      $(this).parent().find(".target").addClass("active");
   }
   });
});
```

Comment: This works exactly as intended, thanks very much. Thanks to everyone else who chimed in, also good alternative options. I'm choosing this one because I think it's the cleanest approach (least amount of code to get the job done.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.container input[type="radio"]').on('change',function(){
     if($(this).is(':checked')){
       $('.target').removeClass('active');
       $(this).closest('.container').find('.target').addClass('active');
     }
     
   });
});
```

```css
.target {
   background-color: red;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}

.active {
   background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
   <div class="target"></div>
   <input type="radio" name="color">
</div>

<div class="container">
   <div class="target"></div>
   <input type="radio" name="color">
</div>

<div class="container">
   <div class="target"></div>
   <input type="radio" name="color">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nearly there. When you select $('.container') in your `each` loop, you are selecting **all** containers. You need to select only the parent container.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.target').each(function(i, targetEl){
      var containerEl = $(targetEl).closest('.container');
      $(targetEl).removeClass('active'); // cleanup first
      if (containerEl.has('input:radio:checked') {
        $(targetEl).addClass('active');
      }
   });
});
```

Alternatively instead of iterating on `.target` elements and going fishing for the parent, you could just iterate on the parents like so:

```js
$('.container').each( function (i, el) {
  var targetEl = $(el).find('.target');
  var inputEl = $(el).find('input');
  targetEl.removeClass('active');
  if (inputEl.is('checked')) {
    targetEl.addClass('active');
  }
});
```